# Cakephp 2.x parked domain https not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, ssl, cakephp-2.1

I have a domain where my code is hosted, and two other domains parked over that domain.

So my code is hosted at domain.com and when I go to domain2.com or domain3.com, the contents of the sites show whatever is hosted at domain.com. The content delivered is based on the url being accessed, so domain2.com would show something different than domain3.com, as I get the url by setting $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

This works just fine for the http versions of the website, but when I try to access any https versions, it gives a cake error:

***URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. 1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting***

That happens on all 3 domains. That page also doesn't have any styling. Cake also can't connect to my database:

***Database connection "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host 'xxx-xx-xxx-x.unifiedlayer.com' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'" is missing, or could not be created.***

I've tried looking for that text inside my app folder, to see if I could at least change the contents of that error page, but if I change the text, it doesn't change it in the error page. I've also tried changing all htaccess files, even deleting their content, but that only affects the http versions, and not the https.

I'm starting to think that the https pages are trying to access a different domain that I have, but I don't see how that would be possible.

All 3 domains have ssl certificates and they were all working correctly before I parked the domains.

Any help is much appreciated. I can also provide more details on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should do exactly what the mysql error says. Flush the hosts from the main database server. Check you have whitelisted your websites on a firewall/iptables.

Comment: I've tried flushing hosts with the root user using FLUSH HOSTS.
Also tried adding the whitelisting the websites on the Remote Mysql, with no results.